# Cannot find PhotogrammetrySession in scope

Tags: macos, realitykit

Trying to compile the Photogrammetry example from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_photogrammetry_command-line_app#overview).

It fails as it does not find the PhotogrammetrySession class. I am on XCode 13 and MacOs 12 Monterey. I have successfully compiled and used the same example with XCode 13 beta and Monterey beta.

Anyone has a clue?

EDIT: adding the part of the code that generates the error (should be obvious but here it is)

```
import RealityKit

let inputFolderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/MyInputImages/")
guard let session = try PhotogrammetrySession(input: inputFolderUrl) else {
    return      }
```

The class is part of the os and I cannot debug it, its just not there after I import RealityKit. The resulting compile error is:

```
Cannot find type 'PhotogrammetrySession' in scope.
```

Now this comes straight from Apple documentation, so I assume I am doing something stupid or I missed some release notes somewhere. I looked and I did not find anything, so I am asking for help here.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue as well. Will post back here if I figure it out

Comment: Found the reason, they removed the MacOS 12 SDK in the XCode 13 release. Update Xcode and it will work again

Comment: Were you able to get it to work? I updated to the xcode beta and macos 12 beta and still same error

Comment: nvm I downloaded the sample app and it successfully built!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but realized i wasn't targeting macOS and that fixed it.
If you're not check if this might help, otherwise please share.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).